# Recereating the Bundles App Shopify Admin section

Tags: shopify-app, remix.run, polaris, shopify-app-extension

I've developed an app that creates bundles, from the sample app. I have a section on the Shopify Admin product page that mimics the Bundles App view, which appears when previewed. It is identical to the screenshot, but without contents.

How do I modify this to show my bundle contents, exactly like the Bundles app does? I cannot locate this in the code.

[image]